# training yolov3-tiny for 2 classess, would it affect the size of the weights file as well as the inference time?

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I want to understand some aspects of object detection. I am using the YOLO model for training. The pre-trained yolov3-tiny model is trained for 80 classes. Suppose its weight file size is 'X' MB and while inferencing it takes 'Y' seconds. I want to train the model for 2 classes only, will this decrease the weight file size and/or inference time?

PS - Inferencing using both weight files(80 classes and 2 classes) is done on the same hardware specifications.